# What Bosh Deployment should be used for a local cluster?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

My team is deploying an application using Cloud Foundry and Bosh (these tools are required by a party outside the dev team, so they're non-negotiable). We're not familiar with bosh, and we saw that [there are a lot of options to deploy it](https://bosh.io/docs/init.html).

We need to deploy our application on our own local cluster, so we can't use AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud. We also don't want to have to learn an IaaS given that we have limited time. Bosh-lite seems the easiest, but running a VM seems wasteful, and we're not sure how useful it will be as we scale our application.

Given that we want to deploy Cloud Foundry on a local cluster, what is the best Bosh deployment option for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independently of running Cloud Foundry on premise and/or in the cloud, BOSH requires to delegate to most of the deployment to a 3rd party CPI component (like AWS, GCE,...).

How is your local cluster managed?

May be you could have a look at this [RackHD CPI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-rackhd-cpi-release) implementation, and look at [RackHD](https://rackhd.github.io/) for hardware management and orchestration.

Comment: Right now we're not really "managing" it in any way - it's literally just eight machines with centOS installed that we're trying to deploy a small cloud on.

RackHD looks like the best bet. Unfortunately it seems nontrivial to set up, so my team may not be able to actually deploy it in our timeframe.

Thank you though!